# DC/OS - Distributed services

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I recently installed DC / OS ( https://dcos.io/ ) . For now, I use it for testing , so my architecture is composed of:
- 1 node Boostrap
- 1 Master node
- 2 Slave node

However, can you explain why DC / OS does not properly distributed services based on available resources on the various nodes ?

[image: node-repartition-ressources]

In my case, all services are installed on the same node. If I have more resources on this node , DC / OS no longer allows me to install new services.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You have configured the second node as a public agent.

If you want to deploy your service on the public agent, you have to set "slave_public" in Deploy New(or Edit) Service -> Optional -> Accepted Resource Roles.